# AQGridView cell need to be tapped twice to trigger didSelectItem

Tags: iphone, aqgridview

I'm using AQGridView for displaying a TableView in grid format.

I've a problem that, randomly, the GridCell needs to be tapped twice to trigger the

```
didSelectItem
```

method.

On the first tap the cell highlights itself, but no didSelectItem method is called.
On the second tap the method is called.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

The Problem occurs probably only, when you reselect the previous selected GridCell.
So you have to add in your `viewDidAppear` the following Statement:

```
[self.gridView deselectItemAtIndex:self.gridView.indexOfSelectedItem animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also just implement `gridView:willSelectItemAtIndex` instead, and return `NSNotFound` so nothing will be selected.